# What is the sha1sum -c equivalent with OpenSSL?

Tags: command-line, openssl, hashsum

I generated checksums for a list of files and stored them a .sha1 file by using the following command:

```
openssl dgst -r -sha1 -out sums.sha1 *
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
sha1sum * > sums.sha1
```

Now what is the openssl equivalent of the following command?

```
sha1sum -c sums.sha1
```

Comment: Are you sure those are equivalent? `openssl dgst -r -sha1 /usr/bin/true`, for example, gives me `f012036ffa0e3f3b6c27892203165a72af55f06d */usr/bin/true`, with a `*` in it.

Comment: I don't believe openssl has an equivalent function. One could probably script one pretty easily though.

Comment: @muru: `sha1sum` also adds a `*` in the output, this is the expected coreutils format as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, got it. With GNU coreutils (8.22, 8.31), it does with the `-b` flag, not without it. Anyway, it seems the `openssl dgst` verify functions are all tied to verifying a signature (so you need to sign it in addition to just getting the digest).